# c++ abstract class takes derived class parameter

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I want to make a class with a member function that takes a reference to another class, where both classes are derived from abstract classes. I get a compiler error that the class Container is abstract because it doesn't implement addElem().

```
class Ielem
{
public:
  virtual void action() = 0;
};

class Elem: public Ielem
{
public:
  void action() {};
  void extra() {};
};

class Icontainer
{
public:
  virtual void addElem(Ielem &elem) = 0;
};

class Container: public Icontainer
{
public:
  void addElem(Elem &elem) { elem.extra(); };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Elem e;
  Container c;
  c.addElem(e);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems like this ought to work, because any reference to an Elem is also a reference to an Ielem. It compiles if I make Container::addElem take a reference to an Ielem. But then Container::addElem() can't call Elem::extra() unless I use dynamic_cast, which isn't available on the embedded compiler I'm using, or a regular cast, which isn't type safe.

Suggestions?

Comment: There are very specific circumstances in which you're allowed to do this, and this is probably not one of them.

Comment: Why don't you add pure `extra()` to the base class?

Comment: In my real code, `extra()` is related to the specifics of the `Elem` class. it wouldn't be meaningful in other `Ielem` implementations, so I don't want to require its implementation by adding it to the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simply that your virtual method doesn't have the same signature as the concrete method which is intended to overload it; so the compiler sees it as a different function entirely and complains because you haven't implemented `void addElem(Ielem &elem)`.  This is one solution, which you probably don't want--

```
class Icontainer
{
public:
  virtual void addElem(Elem &elem) = 0;  //Ielem -> Elem
};
```

It depends on all your other constraints but I think what I would do--and what seems to conform to general design guidelines, e.g. Sutter & Alexandreascu, would be to create an intermediate abstract class with the full interface--

```
class Melem: public Ielem
{
public:
  // void action() {}; //Already have this form Ielem
  void extra() = 0;
};
```

and then

```
class Icontainer
{
public:
  virtual void addElem(Melem &elem) = 0;
};

class Container: public Icontainer
{
public:
  void addElem(Melem &elem) { elem.extra(); }; 
     //*Now* we're implementing Icontainer::addElem
};
```

Comment: The problem here is that `extra()` is now required for all `Icontainer`/`Ielem` implementations. `extra()` is only meaningful in the `Elem` class. (Also, `Melem` doesn't implement `action()`, and doesn't inherit it from `Ielem`, where it's pure virtual.)

Comment: OKay, then maybe templates are your answer.  Overriding requires identical signatures and there's no way to add interface to derived classes that's recognizable to the base class.

Comment: I ended up using an intermediate class in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong way round: the base class `Icontainer` specifies that `addElem` can take *any* `Ielem` object as an argument, but in your derived class you accept *only* `Elem`. This is a "narrower" type, so the contract "I'll accept any `Ielem` you throw at me" specified in the base class is violated.

I think templates would be the solution here. You don't even need the base classes anymore. Something like this:

```
class Elem
{
public:
  void action() {};
  void extra() {};
};

template<typename ElemType>
class Container
{
public:
  void addElem(ElemType &elem) { elem.extra(); };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Elem e;
  Container<Elem> c;
  c.addElem(e);

  return 0;
}
```

As a bonus, you can now use `Container` with *any* type that has an `extra()` function, and it will just work.

Comment: I picked the other answer as the solution because I used an intermediate class, but your answer was the best description of why my code didn't compile. Thank you!